# Which node version will be use as default?

Tags: node.js

In my Linux mint, previous version of nodejs was `v8.10.0` so I decided to upgrade it and after upgrade, I run `nodejs -v` but it is sill reporting `v8.10.0` (after restarting pc too). If I run `node -v` it is reporting **v12.17.0** (which is currently the latest version). I don't know what is the difference between **node and nodejs**.
I run a xyz.js file from both node and nodejs it runs successfuly.

#### You can see some terminal output for your help -

> $ which -a node
> /usr/local/bin/node
> /usr/bin/node
> $ node -v
> v12.17.0
> $ which -a nodejs
> /usr/bin/nodejs
> $ nodejs -v
> v8.10.0

**Is my system using node/nodejs latest version, If not what should I do ?**

Answer (score 0):

What's happening here is simply the new version of node installs as 'node' while the older version installed as 'nodejs'. Given that your older version of 'nodejs' was working fine and the new version, 'node', never overwrote it you're left with two different versions of node. As a test, I change the name of the node file and or remove it from the folder altogether and see what happens. I'm sure you will be left with only on the version of node being recognized on your system.